# Copy columns from one datatable to another datatable

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I've following requirement.
I've two data tables structured as follows:

dt1:
columns: PrimaryKey, Style, Color, OTS0, OTS1
data:       1                  S1     C1      5          6
               2                  S1     C2      1          2

dt2:
columns: PrimaryKey, Style, Color, OTS2, OTS3
data:       1                  S1     C1      1          2
               2                  S1     C2      3          4

I need to merge above two data tables and the final result data table should be structured as below:
dtResult:
columns: PrimaryKey, Style, Color, OTS0, OTS1, OTS2, OTS3
data:       1                  S1     C1      5          6         1          2
               2                  S1     C2      1          2         3          4

how can we achieve this? (is there any direct way with out using Linq?) Please help!!

Comment: I think what you want is [`SELECT INTO`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp).

Comment: If you can make a primary key column for both tables, maybe consider merging the 2 datatables (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Just to be clear, you're talking about .NET DataTable objects and not database tables, right?  The distinction is VERY important and that's why you should say "DataTable" if that's what you mean and not "data table", which is open to interpretation.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution using .NET or SQL? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data tables have the same number of rows, this might work:

VB.NET:

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim i2 As Integer
Dim Colinx As Integer
Do Until i = dt1.Columns.Count
If dt1.Columns(i).ColumnName.Contains("OTS") Then
Colinx = dt2.Columns.Count
dt2.Columns.Add(dt1.Columns(i).ColumnName, GetType(Integer))

i2 = 0
Do Until i2 = dt2.Rows.Count
dt2.Rows(i2)(Colinx) = dt1.Rows(i2)(i)
i2 = i2 + 1
Loop

End If
i = i + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL database datatable :  Use select into statement....

.net Datatable Object : (I am assuming you have all key from dt1 in dt2)

```
    dtresult = dt1.Copy

    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds.Tables.Add(dtresult )
    ds.Tables.Add(dt2)
    ds.Relations.Add("KeyRelation", dt2.Columns("Key"), dtresult .Columns("Key"))

    dtresult .Columns.Add("OTS2", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"), "Parent.OTS2")
    dtresult .Columns.Add("OTS3", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"), "Parent.OTS3")


    dtresult.AcceptChanges()
```